# how to get list index using react-native-swiper-flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

the library quotes the getCurrentIndex function, but I can't implement it in my code. Could someone show me an example of use? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `ref` via the `ref` prop to the component. This will give you access to the `getCurrentIndex` function.

Here is a minimal example.

```js
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
const App = () => {
  const scrollRef = React.useRef(null);

  return <View style={styles.container}>
    <SwiperFlatList
      ref={scrollRef}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(scrollRef.current.getCurrentIndex())} style={{width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: "red"}}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
  </View>
};
```

The above will print the current index `onPress` of the rendered item. The key part is `scrollRef.current.getCurrentIndex()`.